# Issue with the insert in to a table having a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi guys im writing this new question because, after reading almost all the relative question to this issue, i still don't understand why mysql trigger this error:

---

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (progetto_pal.corso, CONSTRAINT corso_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY
>   (CodiceFiscale_IstrCorso) REFERENCES istruttore (CodiceFiscale))

---

Reading all about this error i know that can trigger because of the type of data, because the element that i go to insert don't pass the check because i doesn't exists in the primary table.

Now i already checked that the elemnet that i go to insert into the table corso :the type is the same and the element exist also in the table istruttore.
As i get to know till now is as if the element that i go to insert into column CodiceFiscale_IstrCorso don't match any of the row in table istruttore.

So what i can do to understand what is wrong im working on phpmyadmin for work on the database and for the insert im using simple form in php now i post the code for sql part of the form.

```
<?php

include('../connDB.php');

class corso{

    public $cc;
    public $des;
    public $cfi;


    function __construct ($cc, $des,$cfi){

        $this->cc=$cc;
        $this->des=$des;
        $this->cfi=$cfi;

    }

    function insRec(){
        global $mysqli;

        $query = "insert into Corso (Codice_Corso, Descrizione, CodiceFiscale_IstrCorso)
        values ('$this->cc', '$this->des', '$this->cfi')";

        if (!$mysqli->query($query)) {
            die($mysqli->error);
        } else {
            header("location: ../insert.php");
        }
    }
}   

    $operaz=(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["operaz"]) ? $_POST["operaz"] : "");

    if($operaz=='insert'){
        $cc=(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["ccC4"]) ? $_POST["ccC4"] : "");
        $des=(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["desC4"]) ? $_POST["desC4"] : "");
        $cfi=(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["cfiC4"]) ? $_POST["cfiC4"] : "");

        $checkIns = new corso($cc, $des, $cfi);
        $checkIns->insRec();
    }

?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Show us the database schemas for the two tables.

Comment: this is not a problem because this will be a project that will not go online so it will not have problem of security

Comment: @Roberto Reibaldi We need to see your tables structure and how you have your foreign keys.

Comment: This is MySQL syntax, please approve removing SQL Server tag

Comment: @RobertoReibaldi You should _never_ knowingly write insecure code. It doesn't matter if it currently only is a "private project". Before you know it, someone will copy paste the code into another project without knowing it's insecure. Another issue is that if any field contains a `'` or ends with a backslash, your query will fail, since the data is completely unescaped. Using Prepared Statements is easy (just an extra line or two) _and_ it will save you time to hunt bugs/refactor your code later.

Comment: Btw, you're missing the opening `'` for the last value in your query.

Answer (score 0):

here are the sql command of the create to the 2 table istruttore and corso

corso:

```
CREATE TABLE `corso` (                                           
`Codice_Corso` char(15) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
`Descrizione` char(40) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,  
`CodiceFiscale_IstrCorso` char(16) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_roman_ci;
ALTER TABLE `corso`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Codice_Corso`),
  ADD KEY `REF_Corso_istru_FK` (`CodiceFiscale_IstrCorso`);
```

istruttore:

```
CREATE TABLE `istruttore` (
  `CodiceFiscale` char(16) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
  `Nome` char(15) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
  `Cognome` char(15) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
  `Indirizzo` char(50) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
  `Provincia` char(2) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
  `Cap` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `Citta` char(10) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `Data_di_Nascita` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_roman_ci; 
  ALTER TABLE `istruttore`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`CodiceFiscale`);
```

Comment: Don't post additional info as an answer. Update your question with all the necessary info.